# How to open react project in a particular chrome profile?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to open react project in a particular profile. Currently, it's opening in my last open or current open chrome profile.

Comment: You likely can't do this through a web application... Would require injecting some malware on the client and force them to reopen Chrome in a specific user profile. Maybe [this is similar](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile) for your own use, but won't be possible without malicious code in a remote host.